# How to get x/y location of each char within a TextBox

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm building an app that generates a gcode print file using SVG font glyphs.
I plan to use a regular `TextBox` on screen for the user but then I need to place each glyph in the corresponding position of it's respective `Char` in the `TextBox` for the print file. (Printer only reads gcode)

For Example:
The user types the message on screen

> Hello World

I then pull the corresponding glyphs "H", "e", "l"... etc and place them on a canvas.
I can get the x/y position of the TextBox itself easily with the following snippet:

```
var ttv = txtBox.TransformToVisual(myCanvas);
Point startPoint = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
```

and this will give me the correct position for the "H" glyph, but does anybody know of a way that I can then calculate the position of the next `Char`? From what I understand, I can use `TransformToVisual` on the `TextBox` itself but not for each individual character within it.

I can't just calculate it with `startPoint + glyph.Width` because there may be multiple lines of text and this would just place every glyph one after another. Additionally, font glyphs can use negative and positive values within its bounding box (script fonts often do this to ensure each letter links itself together nicely) so that could get very messy. I'm hoping there's a much simpler way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: In WPF there is a Class named `FormattedText` for that  - calculate the size and offsets of formatted Text and also individual substrings or chars within. Maybe it or a similar entity also exist in the UWP API?

Comment: I do not think this is a good approach. Non monospace fonts have character depending kerning. So glyphs may partially overlap. I do not think you can get the details you need from a regular textbox. I would try to find some library to convert text to vector drawings that can be used for both on screen display and gcode generation. That should ensure you are actually getting what you see on screen.

Comment: @JonasH - That was my initial approach, but I wasn't able to find anything to convert text to vector graphics in UWP. The glyphs will work fine and they have kerning included with the negative and positive coordinates within the bounding (almost identical to an SVG) so I'm comfortable using these glyphs in my output file - I suppose what I'm really wanting is a way to use these glyphs on the front-end to replace regular text. I can use the Path Data to draw on screen, but no idea on how to create a custom "TextBox" that will use glyphs instead of text.

Comment: I would consider doing editing of the string separate from the preview drawing. I.e. double click and a dialog pops up and allows for editing of the text. There is probably a better solution, but this sounds like an unusual use case, so I would not expect it to be simple.

Comment: I have to say that there is no API that could get the specific position for each character in the TextBox.